# QDialog is destroyed before I get data form it

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have QDialog that will extract information from it. I added `setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)` to make sure to clean up the GUI, but `QDialog` and its attributes being deleted before extracting them. `Error: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted`.

1. How can I maintain QDialog, until I get information I need, then destroy on Accep or reject (like `deletelater()`)?
2. If the solution is to set `setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)==False`, How can I effectively delete the `QDialog` after accept or reject, to make GUI is not increasing in size?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        
        #
        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel('name')
        self.val   = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.val.setText("{} is my infor".format(name))
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.title)
        hbox.addWidget(self.val)
        
        #
        QBtn = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(QBtn)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        #
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(hbox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
 


def main(): 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Dialog('text')
    if ex.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        myinformation = ex.val.text()
        print(myinformation)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get information from the dialog after closing it then you **should not** use `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)` since at the moment you want to get the information the dialog will be destroyed.

On the other hand it is **not necessary** to use `deleteLater()` since "ex" is a local variable that will be destroyed so there is no memory leak.